# how to position a infowindow above pin using e.PageX and e.PageY values?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im building a map with custom info window, Im trying to position the infowindow based on the clicked event pageX and PageY values of the pin but I'm not sure how to properly achieve this, at the moment all my calculation attempts through up random positions.

**JS**

```
Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(pin, 'click', function(e) {
     instance.displayInfoBox(e, pin, response);
});

$itemOverlay.css({

    top: e.pageX,
    left: e.pageY

}).show();
```

**CSS**

```
.item-overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 200px;
    height: auto;
    background: white;
    padding: 10px;
    display: none;
}
```

**JSFiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/upej8/13/

Answer (score 0):

You mixed the coordinates, the style should be :

```
$itemOverlay.css({

  top:  e.pageY,
  left: e.pageX
}).show();
```